# Call extension method created on parent class overloaded in child class

Tags: c#, .net, oop, extension-methods

- I am having code as below where WebServiceSender is the parent class.
- I have added an Extension method to this as "ExtTest".
- I have one child class "ChildWebServiceSender" inheriting
  WebServiceSender.
- In my child class I am having a method with same signature as
  Extension method, `public WebServiceSender ExtTest(string something)`

Now after creating object of Child class I get intellisense as there are TWO OVERLOADED methods. But I can always call ExtTest from Child class but not the Extension method.

How can I call Extension method ExtTest?

```
public class WebServiceSender : IMessageSender
{
    public void SendMessage(string subject, string body)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Web Service\n{0}\n{1}\n", subject, body);
    }
}
public static class util 
{
    public static WebServiceSender ExtTest(this WebServiceSender abc, string something)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am into extension");
        return new WebServiceSender();
    }
}

public class ChildWebServiceSender : WebServiceSender
{
    public WebServiceSender ExtTest(string something)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am in instance");
        return new WebServiceSender();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ChildWebServiceSender d = new ChildWebServiceSender();
        d.ExtTest("abc");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is bad design and just asking for trouble. Name your methods in a proper way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call extension method you should cast and call it as from the base class:

```
((WebServiceSender)d).ExtTest("abc");
```

And surely you could call it explicit from your extension class:

```
util.ExtTest(d, "tra");
```

And i agree with comments and Jon Skeet. That you need this is actually a code smell and makes your code not very readable.

Comment: That Worked. Thank you

Comment: @GufranKhan  if that worked you could upvote answer and mark it as a solution :)

Answer (score 8):

> How can i call Extension method ExtTest ?

Instance methods will always be preferred over extension methods - the compiler only checks for extension methods after everything else has failed.

In this case, the simplest approach is just to use a variable of type `WebServiceSender` instead:

```
WebServiceSender d = new ChildWebServiceSender();
d.ExtTest("abc"); // This will call the extension method
```

The execution-time type of `d` doesn't matter - only the compile-time type.

If you need to call methods from `ChildWebServiceSender` as well, you can just use two variables which refer to the same object:

```
ChildWebServiceSender child = new ChildWebServiceSender();
WebServiceSender baseRef = child;
child.ExtTest("abc"); // This will call the child instance method
baseRef.ExtTest("abc"); // This will call the extension method
```

(You can use a cast instead, of course - I figured this would be clearer to read. The main point is that you want an expression of type `WebServiceSender` as the target for the method call.)

Or you could just call the method as a regular static method:

```
// TODO: Rename "util" to follow .NET naming conventions
util.ExtTest(d, "abc");
```

Or, better, you could rename either your extension method or your instance method so that they don't conflict - that will make it clearer to anyone *reading* the code which you're trying to call.

Comment: But then using the object "d" i can not call d.ExtTest("abc") from child class. I should be able to call both methods from single object

Comment: @GufranKhan: You should have said that's what you wanted. You only described wanting to call the extension method... will edit, but please try to be more clear in future.

Comment: Sorry for the addition in the question at last moment. Thanks Though :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to call it as if it were a regular static method, rather than calling it as if it were an instance method.  When there is both an extension method an instance method of the same name found by the compiler, the instance method always "wins".